# Magento installation problem: Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: php, magento2

I have problema with magento 2 installation. I have done everything, elasticsearch is working fine.

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/magento" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento_praktika" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="user@example.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="EUR" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host="https://mystore.magento.com" --elasticsearch-port=9200 --elasticsearch-enable-auth=true --elasticsearch-username="elastic" --elasticsearch-password="GPy8TkICgFU6dqYT_X_="
```

When I put this code in my CMD magento folder. I have got this error:

```
  Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

I tried to search information in Google but it didn't help to me.

Answer (score 0):

Make you have install Elastic search on your server.

You can also configure Elastic search after installation magento.

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/magetest/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magetest" --db-user="root" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="test123@admin.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --language="en_US" --currency="INR" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

add following property in \elasticsearch\config\elasticsearch.yml and check  again

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
```